# Spring Security - Couldn't locate: org.springframework.ldap.core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

Im having some weird issues using spring security. When i try to start my tomcat server, the following exception is thrown:

`Couldn't locate: org.springframework.ldap.core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource.  If you are using LDAP with Spring Security, please ensure that you include the spring-ldap jar file in your application;`

I have almost every spring library included in my maven dependencies:

> spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar 
>   spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar 
>   spring-security-config-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar 
>   spring-security-ldap-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-security-acl-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-security-taglibs-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-aop-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-context-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-jdbc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-asm-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-expression-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar

What could be possibly causing this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your runtime classpath, rather than maven configuration. It should be in `spring-ldap-core`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by simply downgrading to a older version of spring security. No problems happened since then.